# Why does regular expression 'r[1900-2023]+' doesn't returns range of values between 1900 to 2023?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code in Python:

```
txt = 'Ted\'s date of birth is 5-6-2005 and he started college at 08-5-2019'

year = re.compile(r'[1900-2023]+')

res = year.findall(txt)

for i in res:
    print(i)
```

the code above returns:

```
200
0
2019
```

since `[1900-2023]` returns any match between range of `1900` to `2023`, why here it returned 200 and 0 which is out of this range? Moreover it even didn't return 2005 which is within this range.

Comment: *"since [1900-2023] returns any match between range of 1900 to 2023"*: no, it's wrong. `-` defines a range between characters only, not between strings or numbers.

Comment: `[1900-2023]` means any characters in the group {1, 9, 0, {0, 1, 2}, 0, 2, 3} where the inner group comes from the range `0-2`. The expression is equivalent to `[01239]`.

Comment: `[0-9] Returns a match for any digit between 0 and 9` I saw this explanation and it was a bit vague, now you shaded light upon it more. 
Thank you for taking time and helping me out.

Comment: You may automatically generate such ranges, there are a lot of Web sites where you may generate these regexps for free, [here is one of them](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in other answers/comments, `[1900-2023]` does not match any number between `1900` and `2023`, rather matches any character that is a `1`, `9`, `0`, `-`, `2`, or `3`. For your specific case, you could make a pattern that matches these numbers on your own:

```
19[0-9]{2}|20[01][0-9]|202[0-3]
```

Explanation:

```
19[0-9]{2}  - "19" and exactly 2 numbers that range 0 - 9 (1900 - 1999)
|           - OR
20[01][0-9] - "20" and either a 0 or 1 and another number that ranges 0 - 9 (2000 - 2019)
|           - OR
202[0-3]    - "202" and one number in a range 0 - 3 (2020 - 2023)
```

Comment: Thank you @dvo for help

Answer (score 4):

`[1900-2023]` doesn't return any number between `1990` and `2023`. `[` `]` can be used for **character** ranges, not string/numeric ranges. So you can write `[1-9]` or `[a-f]`, but not `[10-20]` or `[aa-zz]`.

I would suggest to find any 4-digit number with `\d{4}` regex then convert it to int and check if it's in the range that interests you.

Comment: Or, more precisely, you *can* write `[10-20]` but it means "one of '1', a character in the range '0'-'2', and '0'" (which is obviously the same as "one of '0', '1', or '2'")

Comment: Depending on the search text, a better re to match might be `([12]\d3)` (you *can* write an re to match exactly, but it's painful)

Comment: `[1900-2023]+` == `([190]|[0-2]|[023])+` (`-` makes a range only between characters, the rest of the square brackets works independently as per square brackets regex rules) == `[01239]+`.